# How can I install es_AR locale on OSX El Capitan?

Tags: macos, unix

I'm trying to install a locale on OSX (El Capitan) and I can't figure it out.

I've been googling for hours now.

In Ubuntu is as simple as `locale-gen` and `dpkg-reconfigure`.

I'm coding a PHP application that uses `es_AR` as a locale and I can't get my number formatting right.

Works fine in Linux systems.

```
$ locale -a | grep es
es_ES
es_ES.ISO8859-1
es_ES.ISO8859-15
es_ES.UTF-8
```

Answer (score -1):

You would set that up in the *Languages and Region* setting in *System Preferences*

[image]

Under the advanced tab, you can set your number formatting

[image]

Comment: Hi Allan! I only see "Spanish", "Spanish (México)" and "Spanish (Latin América)" but I need "Spanish (Argentina)"

Comment: Wouldn't that be Spanish (Latin America) then?

Comment: Nop. If I run `locale -a` on my terminal I don't see `es_AR` listed.

Comment: What I mean is es_AR is covered under the Spanish (Latin America) locale?

Comment: In Linux/Unix and Mac es_AR is really the exact same as the es_ES and es_419 locales. See my answer on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38338064/1861357).

Comment: From what I can tell, _no_ language+region you install via System Preferences installs a corresponding underlying _Unix_ locale (as would be reflected in `locale -a`).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you can set it up. As you have self figured out, OS X doesn't care much for countries in Latin America and out them all together.

However, as what you need is to test your PHP application, you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18471880/4200050) out. There are some steps you can do to force the locale.

There is otherwise the ability of the web browser to emulate another locale that the one of the OS. You should check the documentation of your browser, most of them have developer tools which can be useful. Another option is to look for some browser plugin.